# Tk installation with CPAN

Tags: windows, perl, tk-toolkit, cpan

I want to write GUI in perl by using the Tk module. Therefore, I want to install Tk module.

I opened a command window, and typed "cpan Tk". After a few minutes the run was over and then I got the following message on the command window:

""windres' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. dmake.exe: Error code 129, while making 'tkres.o' dmake.exe: Error code 255, while making 'pTk\libpTk.a' SREZIC/Tk-804.032.tar.gz C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK"

Apparently, the installation didn't go well. I also tried to execute a perl script that contains the line "use Tk" and I got the following message:

""Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tk module) 
(@INC contain s: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at file.pl line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at file.pl line 1."

Can you help me install Tk properly?

Answer (score 2):

After installing CPAN module with command **perl -MCPAN -e "shell"**, 
add path  **c:\Perl\site\lib\auto\MinGW\bin** to system PATH and restart window with CPAN console.

Then commands '**make Tk**', '**test Tk**' and '**install Tk**' in CPAN console should work.

Comment: `perl -MCPAN -e "shell"` runs CPAN in shell mode, it doesn't install CPAN. To run this normally just type `cpan` from the command prompt. also `make Tk` and `test Tk` are redundant when the third thing you suggest is `install Tk`, which does a make test and install in one.

Comment: this was absolutely my problem. Thanks. it works great

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the "Perl Package Manager"? It's located in your Perl directory under "bin/wperl.exe."

Copy the location of the file and type this in the cmd window.

'Location of wperl.exe' -x '"Location of ppm.bat"'
Example :

```
C:\Perl\bin\wperl.exe -x "C:\Perl\bin\ppm.bat"
```

ppm.bat should be in the same folder.

An easier way to launch that would be from your start menu in the "All Programs" section under your Perl Directory. There should be a "Perl Package Manager" there.

It's basically a GUI that allows you to locate every module on the CPAN website. From there you can find Tk (which I don't know, but I assume it's http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk-804.030/).

Comment: I found that file and I can't execute it. I double click it and no response

Comment: Sorry, incomplete response from me. Try the edit that I just made.

Comment: PPM is not really an option for the poor guy.  Check out http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Tk/ .  If he wants Tk, he'll have to do it the hard way.  The folks at ActiveState have been pushing Tkx. I think it's better for new work, but can be a grind translating older programs.