# Trouble installing Tk module for perl using CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install the Tk module in Strawberry Perl using  `cpan install Tk`, but I get the following error message.

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '\c\Users\Pravi\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 18 May 2020 17:55:59 GMT
Running install for module 'Tk'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.09)
Checksum for \c\Users\Pravi\.cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SR\SREZIC\Tk-804.035.tar.gz ok
The system cannot find the path specified.
Uncompressed \c\Users\Pravi\.cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SR\SREZIC\Tk-804.035.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/usr/bin/tar xf "Tk-804.035.tar":
The system cannot find the path specified.
Couldn't untar Tk-804.035.tar: child exited with value 1
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.29)
  SREZIC/Tk-804.035.tar.gz
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
```

I am confused by the "System cannot find the path specified" and am wondering how I can fix this issue.

[Tk installation with CPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200564/tk-installation-with-cpan)

I have tried following the steps here but it looks like this for ActivePerl and NOT Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Please provide the output of `echo o conf | cpan | perl -nle"print if /\b(?:tar|Config\.pm)\b/"`

Comment: Tip: The command is `cpan Tk`, not `cpan install Tk`. In addition to installing `Tk`, the latter also installs a module named `install` (which is just a dummy module because so many people do what you did)

Comment: even then the output is still the same `cpan install Tk`

Comment: the output to the command you put is `tar                [/usr/bin/tar]`

Comment: That's not right. And wasn't there another line output? Try this one instead: `echo o conf | cpan | perl -nle"print if /(?:\btar|Config\.pm)\b/"`

Comment: `cpan[1]> $CPAN::Config options from C:\Users\Pravi\.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm:
    tar                [/usr/bin/tar]`

Comment: thats what I get if I ran that ine same thing except in command form.

Comment: That file wasn't created by Strawberry Perl, and I think it's overriding SP's. Rename that file, then try `cpan Tk` again. (You can always rename it back if you need to.)

Comment: interesting so when I rename that it gives alot more text back than I  can paste here....

Comment: Is it installing modules or configuring `cpan`?

Comment: installing modules.(I want to install the `Tk` Module) and it says `Install Failed for Tk module` at the end. so I know it is aiming the right direction.

Comment: Note that I successfully installed Tk with SP earlier today. Out of curiosity, what's the output of `where cpan`?

Comment: `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan.bat`

Comment: its shows twice so do you think that is causing problems?

Comment: ok, good. Just making sure the right `cpan` was being used

Comment: Not sure what that means --I just discovered `where` a few minutes ago-- but I'm not concerned. (I get something equivalent.)

Comment: was trying to ask if cpan being installed in 2 diff locations was the issue.

Comment: I know. And my comment was a reply to that. I did figure out a bit since. `where` finds all matches in the PATH, where a match is an exact match or one with an "executable extension" (`.com`, `.exe`, `.bat`, `.cmd`, etc). I expected `where` to be like `bash`'s `type` which tells you what prog would be executed, but it's not quite. The first match (`bin\cpan`) is a Perl script, but Windows won't try to execute that. The second match (`bin\cpan.bat`) is created from the first when Perl is installed and is what Windows is running. This is all normal.

Comment: do other modules happen to conflict with Tk which results in this installation failing?

Comment: Is speculating about problems other than the ones you are having really what you want to do?

Comment: @ikegami `cpan install` should actually catch that special case and not install the `install` module. And, there's the `-J` switch which will dump the config as Perl, although I now think that it would be nice to have json output that you can slice with `jq`.

Comment: @briandfoy Sounds super. I'll look into this.